# Does the Android "OpenVPN Connect" client app let my tablet to have an connectable IP address

Tags: android, openvpn

I want to know that would the official Android OpenVPN client app ["OpenVPN Connect"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn&hl=en) provides us an IP address of my Android 4.4.2 tablet so that I could ping it (or use it somehow) from my home OpenVPN server side.

I want a scenario that my Android tablet could be reachable from my home Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 server even when the tablet leaves my home (i.e. connecting through 3G/4G). So that I could install some servers (e.g. ftp, samba) in my Android tablet and reach these servers from my home Ubuntu server (assume I am sitting in my home and my Android tablet is holding by my friend).

I've heard that if I root my Android tablet and install the OpenVPN Linux client in it then I would achieve my proposed scenario. However, Android 4.0+ seems have introduced new API for VPN ([VpnService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html)). So I wonder that could a non-root Android 4.4.2 tablet achieves my scenario in a more easy way.

I am evaluating whether it is worth to install the OpenVPN server in my home Ubuntu computer. Does anyone have such experience to share.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the correct settings, OpenVPN will provide a remote device with a "local" IP address, and you can use that address to access the device. I currently use this to RDP from my android device to other devices on the network, though the device is accessible in the other direction, and will regularly use it to provide remote assistance to devices that have VPN'd to my network.

You currently do not need to have rooted your device (4+) to use [this OpenVPN client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn), which states that it:

> Supports Ice Cream Sandwich, Jelly Bean and higher. Does NOT require a rooted device

Comment: I have installed the "OpenVPN Connect" app in my Android 4.4.2 tablet but have not yet connected to any OpenVPN server as I have not yet installed / configured one in my home Ubuntu server. I understand your answer as if I now install / configure an OpenVPN server in my home and use the "OpenVPN Connect" app in my Android tablet, then I could ping (or use somehow) my Android tablet from my home server through 3G/4G connection. Correct me if I have any mis-understanding of your answer, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You should be able to access the Android device as it were present on the local network, using the VPN provided IP address.

Comment: Then should I obtain the "local" IP address of my Android tablet from the "OpenVPN Connect" app, or from my home OpenVPN server. (I am sorry if I have asked a naive question as a new comer to OpenVPN)

Comment: Not a worry - it will list your IP in both the admin console on the server, and the application on your tablet. My use of the word local was just to emphasize that you weren't using the WAN IP of the tablet device.

Comment: Thanks for a good sharing of your experience. I now confirm that it's worth for me to install / configure an OpenVPN server in my home. You have saved me a lot of searching time.

Comment: If you think my answer is the "best solution to your problem", would you mind accepting it?